# Handle self written types definition in TypeScript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

In my React project using TypeScript I wrote some types definition that I need to reuse in many other files like for example the type:

```js
type TIconName = 'menu' | 'shop' | 'user'
```

To make this type available in all my project I use a `types.ts` file that lies at the root and that export all my types:

*/types.ts*

```js
export type TIconName = 'menu' | 'shop' | 'user' 
...
```

So now I'm able to import all the types like this one in all my files with only one import:

*/component/icon/Icon.tsx*

```js
import { TIconName, TOtherType, ... } from '../../types'
...
```

With the use of an alias `@types` that refer to `types.ts` it makes importing even easier:

*/component/deeperComponent/component.tsx*

```js
import { TIconName, TOtherType, ... } from '@types'
...
```

---

My type `TIconName` belong to the React component `/component/icon/Icon.tsx` which is basically typed with an interface for his props:

*/component/icon/Icon.tsx*

```js
import React from 'react'
import { TIconName } from 'types'

interface Props {
  iconName: TIconName
}

// C O M P O N E N T
const Icon: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  ...
```

My problem is I'd like to get access to this type without having to import him like React do with his type `React.FunctionComponent<...>`.

I know in order to do that I'd have to write a `.d.ts` file. So I wrote one called `index.d.ts` in the same folder that my `Icon` component:

*/component/icon/index.d.ts*

```js
type TIconName = 'menu' | 'shop' | 'user'
```

But if I import my `Icon` component in an other file, typescript doesn't recognize/import the type `TIconName`:

*/component/user/User.tsx*

```js
import Icon from '../icon/Icon'

const test: TIconName   // <- Cannot find name 'TIconName'
```

Do you have any idea what I forgot or where the problem is?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html

Comment: @ritaj Thanks for the link but can you please be more specific of what my error is ? Because I wrote my type definition in a `global` but it's still not work: `declare global {
  type TIconName = 'menu' | 'shop' | 'user' 
}`. And just read the structure of this `.d.ts` file don't help me more :(