# Typescript declaration merging cause refers to a value, but is being used as a type here in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to find a way to avoid racking my brains to think out a name without breaking elegant with suffix or prefix to diff declaration and component name.

I'm inspired by this link[Avoid duplicate identifier between objects and interfaces in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60773923/avoid-duplicate-identifier-between-objects-and-interfaces-in-typescript)
 to use declaration merging. But it seems everything just mess up after merging. It neither detects type nor value.

Sample files:

```js
//Player.tsx
interface Player {
  id: number
  name: string
  status: string
  avatar: string
}

const Player: React.FC<Player> = ({name, status, avatar}) => (
  <div className="flex">
    <span className="block w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-green-200">{avatar}</span>
    <span className="pl-5 flex flex-col justify-center">
      <p className="text-lg">{name}</p>
      <p>{status}</p>
    </span>
  </div>
)

export default Player
```

In this way, I got error:

```js
//ListPlayer.tsx
import Player from './Player';

export interface Props {
  items: Player[]  //'Player' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Player'?
}
const ListPlayer: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <Player {...item} />
    ))}
  </>
);
export default ListPlayer;
```

If I use typeof, upper error will be fixed but, got another error:

```js
//ListPlayer.tsx
import Player from './Player';

export interface Props {
   items: typeof Player[]
}
const ListPlayer: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <Player {...item} /> //Type '{ propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<Player> | undefined; contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined; defaultProps?: Partial<Player> | undefined; displayName?: string | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Player': id, name, status, avatarts(2739)
    ))}
  </>
);
export default ListPlayer;
```

I wonder what's the problem in my codes?

Answer (score 1):

You confuses items props with Player component.

Define PlayerProps interface and export it:

```
import React from 'react'
export interface PlayerProps {
  id: number
  name: string
  status: string
  avatar: string
}

const Player: React.FC<PlayerProps> = ({name, status, avatar}) => (
  <div className="flex">
    <span className="block w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-green-200">{avatar}</span>
    <span className="pl-5 flex flex-col justify-center">
      <p className="text-lg">{name}</p>
      <p>{status}</p>
    </span>
  </div>
)

export default Player
```

For ListPlayer you should define props using interface PlayerPros like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import Player, {PlayerProps} from './Player';

export interface Props {
  items: PlayerProps[]
}
const ListPlayer: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <Player {...item} />
    ))}
  </>
);
export default ListPlayer;
```

Comment: Your way works and I do adapt this way in my project.However, I'm not sure whether you read the link I post (I edit my question to stress that link) which give me an idea to avoid struggle in naming the component and declaration. Unluckily I failed.  I want to know any chance I can make it?