# Weird behavior in typescript when export same named interface and variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Normal case 1:

```js
//ListPlayer.tsx
import Player from './Player';

export interface Props {
  items: Player[]
}
const ListPlayer: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <Player {...item} />
    ))}
  </>
);

export default ListPlayer;
```

```js
//Player.tsx
interface Player {
  id: number
  name: string
  status: string
  avatar: string
}

const Player: React.FC<Player> = ({name, status, avatar}) => (
  <div className="flex">
    <span className="block w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-green-200">{avatar}</span>
    <span className="pl-5 flex flex-col justify-center">
      <p className="text-lg">{name}</p>
      <p>{status}</p>
    </span>
  </div>
)

export default Player
```

Normal case 2:

```js
//ListPlayer.tsx
import Player from './Player';
//both this and above code works
//import {Player} from './Player';

export interface Props {
  items: Player[]
}
const ListPlayer: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <Player {...item} />
    ))}
  </>
);

export default ListPlayer;
```

```js
//Player.tsx
export interface Player {
  id: number
  name: string
  status: string
  avatar: string
}

export const Player: React.FC<Player> = ({name, status, avatar}) => (
  <div className="flex">
    <span className="block w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-green-200">{avatar}</span>
    <span className="pl-5 flex flex-col justify-center">
      <p className="text-lg">{name}</p>
      <p>{status}</p>
    </span>
  </div>
)

export default Player
```

However if do some change on `export`, I will encounter error.
Error case:

```js
//ListPlayer.tsx
import Player from './Player';

interface Props {
  items: Player[] //'Player' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Player'?
}
const ListPlayer: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <Player {...item} />
    ))}
  </>
);

export default ListPlayer;
```

```js
//Player.tsx
export interface Player {
  id: number
  name: string
  status: string
  avatar: string
}

const Player: React.FC<Player> = ({name, status, avatar}) => (
  <div className="flex">
    <span className="block w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-green-200">{avatar}</span>
    <span className="pl-5 flex flex-col justify-center">
      <p className="text-lg">{name}</p>
      <p>{status}</p>
    </span>
  </div>
)

export default Player
```

can anyone explain why named export or default export will make difference in this example?

Comment: Don't you have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274234/typescript-declaration-merging-cause-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-t) already?

Comment: Nope, I want to figure out why why it complain error if I exported the interface?